# std::vector insert error

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector code in c++ this:

```
typedef  vector<boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> >::iterator traveling;
traveling running = 
std::partition( wait.begin(), wait.end(), tuple_comp    );
running_jobs.insert(running, wait.end());
wait.erase( running, wait.end() );
```

And this error is giving me:

```
main.cpp:223: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, std::allocator<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >
>::insert(threaded_function(ppa::Model_factory&, ppa::Node*)::traveling&,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>*, std::vector<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, std::allocator<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> > > >)’
```

This is netbeans 7.2, I don't know vector in std is supposed to have insert, am I missing something?

```
running_jobs = vector<boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> > running_jobs;

 line 223    running_jobs.insert(running, wait.end());
```

Comment: We would need to see the definition of `running_jobs`. Looks like you are mixing up types. The error says that there is no fitting `insert` member function.

Comment: most likely this is because the *type* of `running_jobs` is different to the *type* of `wait`!

Comment: both are vectors of tuples the same data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed your call to `insert`. Take a look at
 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/

You must tell `insert` where to insert into `running_jobs`. probably something like:

```
running_jobs.insert(running_jobs.end(), running, wait.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

what is running_jobs?I take it its a vector. also the object "wait" I assume its a vector

for the call

```
running_jobs.insert(running, wait.end());
```

is wrong. first param must be the iterator
so the right call should be

```
running_jobs.insert( wait.end(), running);
```

hope this works

Comment: Nope, running_jobs.insert(wait.end(), running); same thing, main.cpp:223: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, std::allocator<boost::tuples::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, etc...